# No authentication challenges found while using twitter4j library

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, twitter4j

I am currently working on integrating Twitter in my android application. I integrated it successfully to an extent. However I get the `No authentication challenges found` exception in following scenario.

1. I use `App-only authentication` (without loging into twitter)to fetch the public feeds from twitter. I fetch them successfully.
2. When I try to reply or retweet or mark it as favorite, I check if user is already logged in or not, if  it is not logged-in then I try to login first and then do the reply or retweet.
3. But I get above mentioned exception while trying to login only, so I don't reach the reply or retweet.

**Note:** If I  don't use `App-only authentication` and choose to login directly(without fetching public feed), then it works fine and I can login.

**Following is the stacktrace:**

```
11-14 19:33:03.597: W/System.err(3305): No authentication challenges found
11-14 19:33:03.667: W/System.err(3305): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
11-14 19:33:03.667: W/System.err(3305):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=9ddbeb3a or
11-14 19:33:03.727: W/System.err(3305):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=937eec8d
11-14 19:33:03.747: W/System.err(3305): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[9ddbeb3a-937eec8d c8a7b39b-dc5ea0d9], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.4}
11-14 19:33:03.797: W/System.err(3305):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
11-14 19:33:03.857: W/System.err(3305):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
11-14 19:33:03.897: W/System.err(3305):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
11-14 19:33:03.957: W/System.err(3305):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:145)
11-14 19:33:04.097: W/System.err(3305):     at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:165)
11-14 19:33:04.107: W/System.err(3305):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:381)
```

**EDIT:**

Following is the code I am using to switch the configuration based on whether user is logged in or not.

```
private TwitterInstance(boolean withLoginConfig) {

        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(STAConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(STAConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        // configuration required to fetch feeds without login.
        if (!withLoginConfig) {
            configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
            // IMPORTANT: set T4J to use App-only authentication
            configurationBuilder.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);
            configurationBuilder.setOAuth2TokenType(getOAuth2Token()
                    .getTokenType());
            configurationBuilder.setOAuth2AccessToken(getOAuth2Token()
                    .getAccessToken());
        }
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
        requestToken = null;
    }
```

I searched for the solution on SO and other sites as well, but did not get any.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you plz write the code , that you are using for the authentication purpose

Comment: posted the code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on few things and finally found answer myself to my question. Hence posting here.

> **Issue:** No authentication challenges found

**Reason :** I was not sending `AccessToken` and `AccessTokenSecret` in configuration after Login. Hence it was not getting the authentication data.

**Solution :**

**Step 1:** I use `App-only authentication` (without loging into twitter) to fetch the public feeds from twitter. I fetch them successfully. For this I use `BearerToken` in configuration as follows:

```
   ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
   configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
   configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
   // IMPORTANT: set T4J to use App-only authentication
   configurationBuilder.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);
   configurationBuilder.setOAuth2TokenType(getOAuth2Token().getTokenType());
   configurationBuilder.setOAuth2AccessToken(getOAuth2Token().getAccessToken());
```

**Step 2:** When I try to reply or retweet or mark it as favorite, I check if user is already logged in or not, if it is not logged-in then I try to login first and then do the reply or retweet. For this I use following configuration.

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

This will give me `RequestToken` which in turn will give me the `AccessToken` and `AccessTokenSecret`.

**Step 3 :** Thereafter I use following configuration for subsequent requests without any problem.

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(getAccessToken()); // from sharedPreferences
configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(getAccessTokenSecret()); // from sharedPreferences
```

Comment: could you please right code to get access token and access token secret by sending request token ?

Comment: Hi Ritesh

Me too have to perform same task but I am not able to retweet. I have got user logged in successfully, have obtained access token, access secret as well as bearer token.

Comment: I am adding code block as reply instead of comment as it is too long to post as comment.

Answer (score 0):

After, version 1.1 of [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) authentication is compulsory for all api calls , even for fetching public tweets and searching..
So, you have to add credentials by force:

```
 AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("ACCESS_TOKEN","TOKEN_SECRET");
 twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
```

Full code can be as follows:

```
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(STAConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(STAConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("ACCESS_TOKEN","TOKEN_SECRET");
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        System.out.println(twitter.getUserTimeline("twitter"));
```